# Issue when launching DevCenter on Windows 8.1.

Tags: cassandra, cql

I cannot launch DevCenter as I am getting the following error message when I try to launch DevCenter.exe on my laptop running Windows 8.1 .

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-10-22 19:45:14.680
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "com.datastax.devcenter.rcp.application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.emf.codegen.CodeGen, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.JMerger, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.Generator, org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.WorkflowRunner, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaIndexer.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

When I launched it from a desktop computer (Windows 7), it worked fine. But, I'm trying to make it work on my laptop, but couldn't manage to do it so far. Any ideas on how to solve this ?

Comment: Can you please send us the logs devcenter-feedback@datastax.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to check is if your Windows 32-bit or 64-bit and that your Java version is the same 32/64-bit version? Looking at the error message it looks like a 64-bit version of DevCenter. Please verify that both Windows and Java are also 64bit.

Was this a new install or an upgrade? Be careful not to extract archive files into any existing DevCenter folder as this will result in a mix of old and new files. Download and extract a fresh copy to be certain.

I've also read about pre-release versions of Windows causing similar looking errors because they did not properly identify their os version and the eclipse osgi layer (equinox) is unable to resolve dependencies.

Comment: I used the 64-bit version of DevCenter whereas my Java version was 32-bit. I installed DevCenter 32-bit and now, it works fine. Thank you !